Next-Auth session error while trying to login with credentials or google
I am using Next.js 14 and NextAuth 4 and trying the login using credentials and google provider
When i am running my project in dev mode there is no error and it's working fine as client-side is capturing session using credentials or google but in production server after build when trying to login this is the error in terminal
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
message: 'Client must be connected before running operations'
stack: 'MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations\n + ....

With credentials - The login is happening fine without any client-side error and i am redirecting it to home page and at the very first it's taking session but as soon i refresh the page the session is gone.
With google - The login is not happening and it's taking me again and again to the login page
pakage.json:
"next": "^14.2.2",
"next-auth": "^4.24.7",

Login Component:
import { Form, Formik } from "formik"
import LoginInput from "../inputs/LoginInput"
import { useState } from "react"
import * as Yup from "yup"
import classes from "@/styles/LoginForm.module.scss"
import Link from "next/link"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import Router from "next/router"
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const LoginForm = (props) => {

    const initialValues = {
        login_email: "",
        login_password: "",
        success: "",
        error: "",
        login_error: ""
    }

    const router = useRouter()
    const {callbackUrl} = router.query

    const [user, setUser] = useState(initialValues)
    const {login_email, login_password, success, error, login_error} = user

    const inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        setUser((prevState) => {
            return {...prevState, [name]: value}
        })
    }
    
    const loginValidation = Yup.object({
        login_email: Yup.string().required("Email address is required!").email("Please enter a valid email address"),
        login_password: Yup.string().required("Please enter the password")
    })

    const loginHandler = async() => {
        props.loadingHandler(true)
        props.waitingMessageHandler(true)
        let options = {
            redirect: false,
            email: login_email,
            password: login_password
        }

        const res = await signIn("credentials", options)
        setUser((prevState) => {
            return {...prevState, success: "", error: ""}
        })

        if(res?.error) {
            props.loadingHandler(false)
            props.waitingMessageHandler(false)
            setUser((prevState) => {
                return {...prevState, login_error: res?.error}
            })
        } else {
            return Router.push(callbackUrl || "/shop")
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Formik enableReinitialize
                initialValues={{ login_email, login_password, success, error, login_error}}
                validationSchema={loginValidation}
                onSubmit={() => {loginHandler()}}
        >
            {
                (form) => (
                    <Form method="post" action="/api/auth/signin/email" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" defaultValue={props.csrfToken} />
                        <LoginInput labeltext="Enter Email address :" for="email" name="login_email" placeholder="john@example.com" type="text" onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
                        <LoginInput labeltext="Enter Your Password :" for="password" name="login_password" placeholder="password" type="password" onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
                        <button type="submit" className={classes.button}>Login</button>
                        <Link href="/auth/forgot"><p className={classes.forgot}>Forgot password?</p></Link>
                        <div className={classes.error} >{login_error && (<span>{login_error}</span>)}</div>
                    </Form>
                )
            }
        </Formik>
        </>
    )
}

export default LoginForm

Mongo Connection:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connection = {}

async function connectDB() {
    if (connection.isConnected) {
        console.log("ALready connected to the database.")
        return
    }

    if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
        connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState
        if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
            console.log("Use previous connection to the database")
            return
        }

        await mongoose.disconnect()
    }
    
    const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: false,
    })

    console.log("New connection to the database")
    connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState
} 

async function disconnectDb() {
    if (connection.isConnected) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            await mongoose.disconnect()
            connection.isConnected = false
        } else {
            console.log("Not disconnecting from the database")
        }
    }
}

const db = { connectDB, disconnectDb}
export default db

[...nextauth].js file:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "./lib/mongodb"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import User from "@/models/User"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import db from "@/utils/db"
import { encode, decode } from "next-auth/jwt";

await db.connectDB()

export default NextAuth({
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const email = credentials.email
        const password = credentials.password
        const user = await User.findOne({email: email})
  
        if (user) {
          return SignInUser({password, user})
        } else {
          throw new Error("This email doesn't exist.")
        }
      }
    }),
    // OAuth authentication providers...
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    })
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async session({session, token}) {
      let user = await User.findById(token.sub)
      session.user.id = token.sub || user._id.toString()
      session.user.role = user.role || "buyer"
      token.role = user.role || "buyer";
      return session
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  jwt: { encode, decode },
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
})

const SignInUser = async({password, user}) => {
  if(!user.password) {
    throw new Error("Please enter your password")
  }
  const testPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
  if(!testPassword) {
    throw new Error("Email or Password is incorrect!")
  }
  return user
}

middleware/auth.js:
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export default async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = await getToken({
        req, 
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        secureCookie: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    })

    if (token) {
        req.user = token.sub
        next()
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({message: "Not Signed in"})
    }
    // res.end()
}

Here's how i am capturing session in index.js:
"use client"
import { Fragment } from "react"
import { useSession, signOut } from "next-auth/react"
import db from "@/utils/db";
import Head from "next/head"

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session, status  } = useSession()
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
      </Head>       
      {session ? <p>You are logged in</p> : <p>You are not logged in </p>}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          signOut();
        }}
      >
        Logout
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

